# Nginx не видит изменений в файле

Tags: nginx, centos, mount

Всем привет, такая проблема..
В качестве основной ОС используется Windows, гостевая - CentOS 7, пользуюсь VirtualBox.
В CentOS стоит nginx, для работы с нужными каталогами в nginx("/etc/nginx" и "/usr/share/nginx") создал общие папки в VirtualBox и монтировал, т.е. получилось что данные каталоги "/etc/nginx", "/usr/share/nginx" - монтированные, сами файлы хранятся в удобном месте Windows.
Сделал так, чтобы работать с файлами в привычном текстовом редакторе на основной ОС.

Сама проблема:
Запускаю я nginx в CentOS, загружаю страницу в браузере уже в основной ОС, вижу нужный текст, затем меняю содержимое основного файла index.html на другое в Windows, сохраняю и перезагружаю страницу и вижу одно и то же, т.е. почему-то nginx не видит никаких сохранений в файле, а выводит старый текст.

Самое интересное, что с помощью редактора "vi" в CentOS вижу изменения в файле, а ещё интересней, что когда я просто сохраняю измененный файл с помощью Windows просто через "vi", то nginx сразу видит все изменения.
Вряд ли что-то кэшируется, пробовал заходить с разных браузеров, удалять кэш в браузерах, смотрел папки в которые по идее должны сохранятся файлы в nginx - ПУСТО.

Видимо что-то не так делаю.

Был бы очень благодарен за помощь, хочу очень сильно приступить к практике после прочтения теории о nginx, а тут такая проблема...
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Известная проблема. Надо выключить sendfile в nginx

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже подсказали на другом ресурсе, но почему так происходит?
Вроде хвалят эту директиву, а тут такое..

Comment: Директиву, а не директорию ;). В нормальном режиме она работает отлично. Но общая папка в vitrualbox это совершенно не нормальный режим

Comment: Эта проблема меня за сегодня с ума свела, что я только не пробовал..
Голова не соображает, уже предложение нормально не могу написать, спасибо ещё раз за ссылку и за ответ, теперь все стало на свои места!